# How Do Watchdog Interrupts Function In Assembly

Tags: assembly, watchdog

I am trying to interpret the assembly code for the TI MSP 430 below. As I step through the lines in my debugger, the subroutine "beep02" continues to loop for an amount of time of which I don't know the origin, and then suddenly it jumps into the "WDT_ISR" subroutine.

My assumption is that somehow that watchdog interrupt service is being called when 'the dog barks' and will take the program from the normally functioning code thats in a loop and advance at to the WDT_ISR. Is this correct?

```
        .title  "morse.asm"
;*******************************************************************************
;     Project:  morse.asm
;      Author:  Spencer Gardner
;
; Description:  Outputs a message in Morse Code using a LED and a transducer
;               (speaker).  The watchdog is configured as an interval timer.
;               The watchdog interrupt service routine (ISR) toggles the green
;               LED every second and pulse width modulates (PWM) the speaker
;               such that a tone is produced.
;
;   Revisions:
;
;              RBX430-1                                    eZ430 Rev C
;              OPTION A                                     OPTION B
;           .------------.                               .------------.
;     SW1-->|P1.0^   P3.0|-->LCD_A0         (RED) LED<--|P1.0     P3.0|-->LCD_RST
;     SW2-->|P1.1^   P3.1|<->SDA          (GREEN) LED<--|P1.1     P3.1|<->SDA
;     SW3-->|P1.2^   P3.2|-->SCL                   NC-->|P1.2     P3.2|-->SCL
;     SW4-->|P1.3^   P3.3|-->LCD_RW                NC-->|P1.3     P3.3|-->LED_3 (Y)
;    INT1-->|P1.4    P3.4|-->LED_5 (GREEN)         NC-->|P1.4     P3.4|<--NC
;    INTA-->|P1.5    P3.5|<--RX                    NC-->|P1.5     P3.5|<--NC
;    SVO1<--|P1.6    P3.6|<--RPOT                  NC-->|P1.6     P3.6|<--NC
;    SVO2<--|P1.7    P3.7|<--LPOT                  NC-->|P1.7     P3.7|<--NC
;           |            |                              |             |
;  LCD_D0<->|P2.0    P4.0|-->LED_1 (G)           SW_1-->|P2.0^    P4.0|<--NC
;  LCD_D1<->|P2.1    P4.1|-->LED_2 (O)           SW_2-->|P2.1^    P4.1|<--NC
;  LCD_D2<->|P2.2    P4.2|-->LED_3 (Y)           SW_3-->|P2.2^    P4.2|<--NC
;  LCD_D3<->|P2.3    P4.3|-->LED_4 (R)           SW_4-->|P2.3^    P4.3|<--RPOT
;  LCD_D4<->|P2.4    P4.4|-->LCD_BL            LCD_BL<--|P2.4     P4.4|<--LPOT
;  LCD_D5<->|P2.5    P4.5|-->SPEAKER               NC-->|P2.5     P4.5|-->SPEAKER
;  LCD_D6<->|P2.6    P4.6|-->LED_6 (RED)    (G) LED_1<--|P2.6     P4.6|-->LED_4 (R)
;  LCD_D7<->|P2.7    P4.7|-->LCD_E          (O) LED_2<--|P2.7     P4.7|<--NC
;           .------------.                               .------------.
;
;*******************************************************************************
            .cdecls C,LIST,"msp430.h"       ; include c header

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;   System equates
myCLOCK     .equ    1200000                 ; 1.2 Mhz clock
WDT_CTL     .equ    WDT_MDLY_0_5            ; WD configuration (Timer, SMCLK, 0.5 ms)
WDT_CPI     .equ    500                     ; WDT Clocks Per Interrupt (@1 Mhz)
WDT_IPS     .equ    myCLOCK/WDT_CPI         ; WDT Interrupts Per Second
STACK       .equ    0x0600                  ; top of stack

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;   External references
            .ref    numbers                 ; codes for 0-9
            .ref    letters                 ; codes for A-Z

;  numbers--->N0$--->DASH,DASH,DASH,DASH,DASH,END      ; 0
;             N1$--->DOT,DASH,DASH,DASH,DASH,END       ; 1
;             ...
;             N9$--->DASH,DASH,DASH,DASH,DOT,END       ; 9
;
;  letters--->A$---->DOT,DASH,END                      ; A
;             B$---->DASH,DOT,DOT,DOT,END              ; B
;             ...
;             Z$---->DASH,DASH,DOT,DOT,END             ; Z

;   Morse code is composed of dashes and dots, or phonetically, "dits" and "dahs".
;   There is no symbol for a space in Morse, though there are rules when writing them.

;   1. One dash is equal to three dots
;   2. The space between parts of the letter is equal to one dot
;   3. The space between two letters is equal to three dots
;   4. The space between two words is equal to seven dots.

;   5 WPM = 60 sec / (5 * 50) elements = 240 milliseconds per element.
;   element = (WDT_IPS * 6 / WPM) / 5

;   Morse Code equates
ELEMENT     .equ    WDT_IPS*240/1000

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;   Global variables                        ; RAM section
            .bss    beep_cnt,2              ; beeper flag
            .bss    delay_cnt,2             ; delay flag

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;   Program section
            .text                           ; program section
message:    .string "HELLO CS 124 WORLD"                 ; PARIS message
            .byte   0
            .align  2                       ; align on word boundary

RESET:      mov.w   #STACK,SP               ; initialize stack pointer
            mov.w   #WDT_CTL,&WDTCTL        ; set WD timer interval
            mov.b   #WDTIE,&IE1             ; enable WDT interrupt
            bis.b   #0x20,&P4DIR            ; set P4.5 as output (speaker)
            clr.w   beep_cnt                ; clear counters
            clr.w   delay_cnt
            bis.w   #GIE,SR                 ; enable interrupts

;   output 'A' in morse code
loop:       mov.w   #ELEMENT,r15            ; output DOT
            call    #beep
            mov.w   #ELEMENT,r15            ; delay 1 element
            call    #delay

            mov.w   #ELEMENT*3,r15          ; output DASH
            call    #beep
            mov.w   #ELEMENT,r15            ; delay 1 element
            call    #delay

            mov.w   #ELEMENT*3,r15          ; output DASH
            call    #beep
            mov.w   #ELEMENT,r15            ; delay 1 element
            call    #delay

            mov.w   #ELEMENT*7,r15          ; output space
            call    #delay                  ; delay
            jmp     loop                    ; repeat

;   beep r15 ticks of the watchdog timer
beep:       mov.w   r15,beep_cnt            ; start beep

beep02:     tst.w   beep_cnt                ; beep finished?
              jne   beep02                  ; n
            ret                             ; y

;   delay r15 ticks of the watchdog timer
delay:      mov.w   r15,delay_cnt           ; start delay

delay02:    tst.w   delay_cnt               ; delay done?
              jne   delay02                 ; n
            ret                             ; y

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;   Watchdog Timer interrupt service routine
;
WDT_ISR:    tst.w   beep_cnt                ; beep on?
              jeq   WDT_02                  ; n
            dec.w   beep_cnt                ; y, decrement count
            xor.b   #0x20,&P4OUT            ; beep using 50% PWM

WDT_02:     tst.w   delay_cnt               ; delay?
              jeq   WDT_10                  ; n
            dec.w   delay_cnt               ; y, decrement count

WDT_10:     reti                            ; return from interrupt

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;           Interrupt Vectors
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            .sect   ".int10"                ; Watchdog Vector
            .word   WDT_ISR                 ; Watchdog ISR

            .sect   ".reset"                ; PUC Vector
            .word   RESET                   ; RESET ISR
            .end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question correctly, but yes, interrupts of course interrupt the normal program flow, hence the name. When a particular interrupt is triggered, the processor saves the current `PC` and `SR` on the stack so it can later return to whatever it was doing. Then it fetches a vector from a predefined address and continues execution there. Your code has the vector table at the end, containing an entry that specifies you want `WDT_ISR` invoked for watchdog interrupts. That routine increments the counters then ends with an `IRET` instruction, so the processor reloads the saved `PC` and `SR` and continues execution of the main program.

As for the interval, the initialization code sets that up to occur every 500 microseconds, then the beep/delay just waits for the appopriate number of interrupts to happen.